# Density of Cliques in Random Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I've found and read a considerable amount about the density of cliques on non-random graphs, notably the paper "The Clique Density Theorem" by Reiher. I was wondering if there was any analogous work on the density of cliques on random graphs? I would love to learn about any results out there.

Answer (score 2):

If by "density" you do not *strictly* restrict your question to *quantitative* results (in the sense of results about the numerical value of the clique density), but rather also more *qualitative/structural/topological* results, then the work of Matthew Kahle is very relevant to your question.

In particular, Kahle investigated the *clique complex* of $G(n,p)$. (Synonyms: *flag complex*, *Vietoris--Rips complex*). This is the abstract finite simplicial complex whose $d$-dimensional independent sets are precisely the $(d+1)$-cliques in the graph.

However, if you really *mean* "analogous work", in particular, analogous to theorems of Reiher, and of Razborov, in particular "work discovering a globally-convex-yet-piecewise-concave-dependency between $K^2$-density and $K^r$-density", then I think there simply *does not exist anything* analogous seen through the lens of (the measure of) $G(n,p)$. The dependency between $p$ and $K^r$-density appears convex.

Cf. e.g. [M. Kahle: Sharp vanishing thresholds for cohomology of random flag complexes. Annals of Mathematics 179 (3), pp. 1085-1107](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2014/179-3/p05)

Answer (score 1):

A good start is [Bollobos and Erdös](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/cliques-in-random-graphs/27321102B82EDEEF362556BE714FACD9) (2008), which discusses a lower bound on the minimum number of cliques given statistics of the number of vertexes and edges.